# PHP Array - How to replace value with specific text for same values?

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to create a invoice data but i face problem where the driver name should be replaced with driver number .

for example current array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 20
        [unit_price] => 20
        [driver] => Ivan
        [driver_id] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 10
        [unit_price] => 50
        [driver] => Ivan
        [driver_id] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 20
        [unit_price] => 10
        [driver] => John
        [driver_id] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 20
        [unit_price] => 20
        [driver] => John
        [driver_id] => 5
    )

)
```

i want to change [driver] => Ivan to [driver] => Driver 1 and [driver] => John to [driver] => Driver 2 and so on for the next driver , the problem is data is dynamic and i dont know how to do it , at the end im looking to get result like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 20
        [unit_price] => 20
        [driver] => Driver 1
        [driver_id] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 10
        [unit_price] => 50
        [driver] => Driver 1
        [driver_id] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 20
        [unit_price] => 10
        [driver] => Driver 2
        [driver_id] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 20
        [unit_price] => 20
        [driver] => Driver 2
        [driver_id] => 5
    )

)
```

What i tried to do isnt work correct

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($fetchCustomerProfitIn as $report) {
echo "Driver - $i";
echo "$report['quantity']";
echo "$report['unit_price']";
i ++
}
```

result become incorrect like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [quantity] => 20
    [unit_price] => 20
    [driver] => Driver 1
    [driver_id] => 4
)

[1] => Array
(
    [quantity] => 10
    [unit_price] => 50
    [driver] => Driver 2
    [driver_id] => 4
)

[2] => Array
(
    [quantity] => 20
    [unit_price] => 10
    [driver] => Driver 3
    [driver_id] => 5
)

[3] => Array
(
    [quantity] => 20
    [unit_price] => 20
    [driver] => Driver 4
    [driver_id] => 5
)

)
```

Comment: You could loop over the data and do the replacements, have you tried it yet?

Comment: @NigelRen yes but did not manage to replace their names with Driver 1 , Driver 2 , Driver 3 and so on.... for the current example i got  result like Driver 1,Driver 2,Driver 3,Driver 4 when should be only displayed Driver 1 and Driver 2

Comment: Please add the code you've tried and perhaps we can highlight how it can be made to work.

Comment: So the rule here is that the first name that occurs is replaced by "Driver 1" and so on? Does your array come already sorted by name/id?

Comment: @NigelRen topic updated

Comment: @El_Vanja yes rules are right and i it come sorted but data is dynamic i dont know names or ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try something like this:

```
$drivers = [];

$array = [
    [
        "driver" => "John",
        "quantity" => 30
    ],
    [
        "driver" => "Ivan",
        "quantity" => 25

    ],
    [
        "driver" => "John",
        "quantity" => 20

    ],
    [
        "driver" => "Ivan",
        "quantity" => 22

    ]
];

foreach($array as $key => $arr) {
    if(array_key_exists($arr["driver"], $drivers)) {
        $array[$key]["driver"] = $drivers[$arr["driver"]];
    } else {
        $number = count( $drivers)+1;
        $drivers[$arr["driver"]] = "Driver ".$number;
        $array[$key]["driver"] = $drivers[$arr["driver"]];
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Prints:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [driver] => Driver 1 
        [quantity] => 30 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [driver] => Driver 2 
        [quantity] => 25 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [driver] => Driver 1 
        [quantity] => 20 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [driver] => Driver 2 
        [quantity] => 22 
    ) 
)
```

You basically loop over it, get driver name, and set it as key in $drivers array with value "Driver + count of array (+1)" and you check if key exists, if so, get the value and replace in main array, else create it.

Comment: Just being pedantic, you could factor out the `$array[$key]["driver"] = $drivers[$arr["driver"]];` as it's in both branches of the `if`.